# Regular expression to find entire group which are all optional

Tags: .net, regex

[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4JwN.jpg) to see the structure I am expecting

- `M` for Mandatory
- `O` for Optional

In a file there are several lines e.g. 82, 61, 86.

61 and 86 lines are Repetitive but optional

I need a regex which will pull all the 61 and 86 lines.

I have written like:

```
:61:(.*[\n\r]*)?((?!:86:|:62M:|:62F:).*)?(?!\n|\r)*[\n\r](:86:(((?!:61:|:86:|:62M:|:62F:)[\s\S])*))?
```

but can not make the line `:61:` optional.

Please help me. I have stuck in it.

Bellow is file content

```
:60M:D140430GBP4407412,24
:61:1404300430D597632,9FTRFBARCLAYS CAPITAL//PET002789120
THE CAPITAL GROUP, LONDON
:86:020?00 ?30BARCGB22?3158088306?32BARCLAYS CAPITAL GROUP, LON?33DON
?35GLOBAL REACH PARTNERS LIMIT?36ED      LONDON
:61:1404300430D601528,36FTRFBARCLAYS CAPITAL//PET002954120
THE CAPITAL GROUP, LONDON
:86:020?00 ?30BARCGB22?3158088306?32BARCLAYS CAPITAL GROUP, LON?33DON
?35GLOBAL REACH PARTNERS LIMIT?36ED      LONDON
:61:1404300430D633403,68FTRFBARCLAYS CAPITAL//PET002895120
THE CAPITAL GROUP, LONDON
:86:020?00 ?30BARCGB22?3158088306?32BARCLAYS CAPITAL GROUP, LON?33DON
?35GLOBAL REACH PARTNERS LIMIT?36ED      LONDON
:61:1404300430D1203382,61FTRFGLOBAL REACH PAR//PET025887120
GLOBAL REACH PARTNERS LIMITED
:86:020?00 ?30BARCGB22?3104054305?32GLOBAL REACH PARTNERS LIMIT?33ED
United Kingdom?35CORP FX CLIENTS            ?36        5TH FLOOR
:61:1404300430D1986461,86FTRFBARCLAYS CAPITAL//PET002942120
BARCLAYS CAPITAL GROUP, LONDON
:86:020?00 ?30BARCGB22?3158088306?32BARCLAYS CAPITAL GROUP, LON?33DON
?35GLOBAL REACH PARTNERS LIMIT?36ED      LONDON
:86:051?00 ?30BARCGB22?3120005258088306?32BARCGB5G?35GLOBAL REACH PAR
TNERS LIMIT?36ED LONDON
:61:1404300430C1120,96NTRFBARCLAYS BANK PL//PET600514120
BARCGB5G
:86:051?00 ?30BARCGB22?3120005258088306?32BARCGB5G?35GLOBAL REACH PAR
TNERS LIMIT?36ED LONDON
:61:1404300430C1607,27NTRFBARCLAYS BANK PL//PET601743120
BARCGB5G
:86:051?00 ?30BARCGB22?3120005258088306?32BARCGB5G?35GLOBAL REACH PAR
TNERS LIMIT?36ED LONDON
:62M:D140430GBP9426759,94
```

In the above example each tag i.e inside :: is in the next line.

I try to clear myself. 
The Tag :60M: and :62M: is file specific and can not be replicated but the Tag :61: and :86: lines are optional and replicate. My intention is to capture 61 and 86 lines in a class property which is a list. i.e. a master portion and it's transaction portion. :60M: and :62M: is master portion and :61: and :86: lines are in transaction. I want to match it with regex. and by looping I want to create the class object as Master data and it's transaction data. Please inform if you need any more brief.

Comment: Please don't link us to images. Edit your post and describe your issue here.

Comment: Please add a language tag (java? javascript? python? perl?). Regexp syntax may differ depending on language.

Comment: What should happen if an unknown or wanted row is found?
Where does `62F` come into this?

Comment: Just spotted that this looks like MT940 format - have you checked out [this parser library](https://bitbucket.org/raptux/sharpmt940lib/src)? http://www.raptorious.nl/sharpmt940lib.html

Answer (score 0):

To make something optional in a regular expression is to wrap it in a "non-capturing group" adding a `?` after it.

The question mark at the end makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional.

### Example 1 - Greedy

`(?:anything)?`

```
// Match the regular expression below «(?:anything)?»
//    Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
//    Match the character string “anything” literally (case insensitive) «anything»
```

### Example 2 - Lazy

Adding a 2nd question mark at the end changes the meaning from "greedy" to "lazy"

`(?:anything)??`

```
// Match the regular expression below «(?:anything)??»
//    Between zero and one times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «??»
//    Match the character string “anything” literally (case insensitive) «anything»
```

### Additional Notes

Your requirements are too unclear to give a specific answer - however it's likely everything (or more than expected) is getting selected because you aren't specifying "what you want capture" only "what not to".

E.g. `((?!:86:|:62M:|:62F:).*)?` will capture anything that doesn't start with `:86:` or `:62M:` or `:62F:` - but because there is no "anchor" at the beginning of the capture it will capture everything.

An "anchor" in the case of my description here "is something that must be there", you could use the beginning of a line for example `^` (remembering to use the correct `RegexOptions.Multiline` flags as appropriate).

Or even "the beginning of a line that starts with `:`:

```
^(?=:)
```

Be clear about what should be captured in your question, what are you expecting to get out?

Comment: Making :61: optional if I write (?::61:(.*[\n\r]*))? It is selecting the entire content as the expression do not know from where to start it from the selection. Please suggest

Comment: I've added some additional notes.

Comment: I try to clear myself again The Tag :60M: and :62M: is file specific and can not be replicated but the Tag :61: and :86: lines are optional and replicate. My intention is to capture 61 and 86 lines in a class property which is a list. i.e. a master portion and it's transaction portion. :60M: and :62M: is master portion and :61: and :86: lines are in transaction. I want to match it with regex. and by looping I want to create the class object as Master data and it's transaction data. Please inform if you need any more brief.

Comment: Edit your question and this detail